# React changing order of components does not trigger a re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, ecmascript-6

I'm designing a system that shows when my Heroku apps have been updated. The problem I had was the parent component (`Herokus`) decided the order, but I wanted them to sort based on when they had been updated starting with the most recent. I was able to achieve this, by passing the dates from the `Heroku` component back to the parent `Herokus` component. I tried adding a `console.log(this.state.apps)` which shows the sorted order, but that is not reflected by the rendered component. My guess is react is not seeing the changed order of the components as a reason to update the view - but to be honest I have no clue. Any help is appreciated. Files are below. Sorry, my code is a mess, I rewrote it three times trying to fix this issue.

Herokus Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Heroku from './Heroku';

export default class Herokus extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    var apps = [
      'example-heroku-app'
    ]

    this.state = {
      apps: apps.map((h) => {
        return {
          app: h,
          updatedAt: new Date()
        };
      })
    }
  }

  sortApps() {
    var sorted = this.state.apps.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.updatedAt < b.updatedAt;
    });
    this.setState({
      apps: sorted
    });
  }

  updateParrent(data){
    var apps = this.state.apps;
    apps.find(x => x.app === data.app).updatedAt = data.updatedAt;
    this.setState({
      apps: apps
    });
    this.sortApps();
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    var s = this;

    return (
      <div>
        {s.state.apps.map((app, i) => {
          return (
            <Heroku app={app.app} compact key={`heroku-${i}`} updateParrent={s.updateParrent.bind(s)}/>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Heroku Component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Ping extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        app: props.app,
      updatedAt: new Date()
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var s = this;
    axios.get(`/api/heroku/app/${s.props.app}`, {
        timeout: 20000,
    })
    .then(res => {
        var data = res.data;
      s.setState({
        app: data.app.name,
        updatedAt: new Date(data.app['updated_at'])
      });
      s.props.updateParrent(s.state);

      setInterval(() => {
        var updatedAt = new Date(s.state.updatedAt);
        s.setState({
          updatedAt: updatedAt
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  howLongAgo(date) {
    var ms = new Date() - date;
    var seconds = ms / 1000;
    var n = seconds;
    var suffix = '';

    // less than 1 minute
    if(seconds < 60){
      n = seconds;
      suffix = 'second' + (n > 1.5 ? 's' : '');
    }
    // less than 1 hour
    else if(seconds < 3600) {
      n = seconds / 60
      suffix = 'minute' + (n > 1.5 ? 's' : '');
    }
    // less than 1 day
    else if(seconds < 86400) {
      n = seconds / 3600;
      suffix = 'hour' + (n > 1.5 ? 's' : '');
    }
    // less than 1 week
    else if(seconds < 604800) {
      n = seconds / 86400;
      suffix = 'day' + (n > 1.5 ? 's' : '');
    }
    // more than 1 week
    else {
      n = seconds / 604800;
      suffix = 'week' + (n > 1.5 ? 's' : '');
    }

    return `${Math.round(n)} ${suffix} ago`;
  }

  render() {
    var s = this.state;
    var self = this;
    var output;

    // COMPACT VIEW
    if(this.props.compact){
      output = (
        <div className={'heroku heroku-compact'}>
            <h3>{s.app}</h3>
            <p>{self.howLongAgo(s.updatedAt)}</p>
            <div className='clearfix'></div>
        </div>
      )

    // FULL SIZE VIEW
    } else{
      output = ()
    }

    return output;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that the order changes, but since the keys are based off the `i` index variable, the recorded list still has the same keys in the same order. React therefore does not see a difference.

Example:

Unsorted apps a, b, and c

```
<div key="1"> //app b
<div key="2"> //app a
<div key="3"> //app c
```

Sorted apps

```
<div key="1"> //app a
<div key="2"> //app b
<div key="3"> //app c
```

The apps are now in the right order, but the parent component Herokus still seems them with keys 1, 2, and 3 in the same order.

The solution: 
Change the key to something unique to the individual Heroku components, but something that will remain unchanged unlike `updatedAt`. In this case the most logical choice is the app name.

This can be implemented in the Herokus component's render function like so:

```
export default class Herokus extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var s = this;

    return (
      <div>
        {s.state.apps.map((app, i) => {
          return (
            <Heroku app={app.app} compact key={`heroku-${app.app}`} updateParrent={s.updateParrent.bind(s)}/>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sidney honestly your answer put me on the right track. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I had a similar issue but with a repeater of components that did not change when only the sort order of the store changes, adding a key solved it, thanks man.